# Zipping single file in a single zip without creating a folder

Tags: java, zip

In java most of the zipping apis zips the single file by creating a folder.

For example in windows if we choose to right click-->Winzip-->Add to selected_file_name.zip it creates selected_file_name.zip and if we extract we directly get file rather than a folder and within folder a file.

After extracting by selecting a extract to here only file should come rather than a folder and then a file within that.

Can we do the same using any java api ?

Comment: The Java Zip classes will allow you to name the zip and zip entries whatever you want. Then you can extract the entry to where you want also. It won't do what you want out of the box, but emulating that behaviour can be in Java reasonably simply.

Comment: *"In java most of the zipping apis zips the single file by creating a folder"* What Java zipping APIs have you been looking at? Because none of the built-in Java APIs for working with zip files create any folders on disk. If you're asking about how WinZip works, or how Windows Explorer handles zip file, those are entirely different questions, and has nothing to do with the Java APIs.